# Is there any issue will rise if am going to use post HTTP method for all CRUD operations

Tags: akka-http, http-method

Is there any issue will rise if am going to use **post** **method** for all **CRUD** **operations** in **Akka HTTP** services. why we need to use separate **HTTP method** for **CRUD** operations.

Comment: you can use any http method for anything, its to do with how the server handles the request

Comment: Do you mean issues related to akka-http in particular or to API design in general?

Answer (score 0):

There will not be any "issues" (e.g. failures, exceptions, etc.) that will arise within `akka-http` if you restrict all http methods to be `POST`.  However, it does [violate the definition of RESTful services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming).

Also, you do give up a useful organization technique.  If you organize all read paths inside of GET and all write paths inside of POST, then you can add things like access control (read-only vs. read-write) at the method level.

You therefore lose a level of abstraction for no obvious reason except simplicity.